# Order of the multiplicative group $GL(2,\mathbb Z_{p^n})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$GL(2,\mathbb Z_{p^n})$ denotes the multiplicative group of $2\times 2$ invertible matrices over the ring $\mathbb Z_{p^n}$, for some positive integer $n$ and for each prime $p$.

I know what is the order of $GL(2,\mathbb Z_p)$ for each prime $p$ which is $(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$

But I'm unable to figure it out where is
the difference in computing $GL(2,\mathbb Z_{p^n})$ then $GL(2,\mathbb Z_p)$?

One basic difference is $\mathbb Z_p$ is field but $\mathbb Z_{p^n}$ is not.

But then is this the only reason that the way computing their number of elements are different.

I searched google again and again but found no clue.

Maybe this is so trivial, but I can't figure it out. Sorry also for my poor English.

Please help explicitly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: An integer matrix is invertible modulo $p^2$ iff it is invertible modulo $p$.

Comment: @Unknown cant understand your solution. Please describe in answer box.I can't get your hint.

Comment: @Unknown yes sir, I'm new in exchange, I'll definitely try to use that.

Comment: @Unknown sir, I'm unable to find its order and I'm not getting anything from your hint.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\large m}}\to\mathbb{Z}_p$, inducing a ring homomorphism $M_n(\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\large m}})\to M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, which induces a group homomorphism $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\large m}})\to\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. The kernel is comprised of all $n\times n$ matrices of the form $I_n+pX$ where $X$ is defined wlog in $M_n(\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\large m-1}})$. (Recall that $x\mapsto px$ defines an additive mapping from $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\large m-1}}$ to the multiples of $p$ within $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\large m}}$.)

Comment: then? I've to find order of GL(n, p^m), from your hint i really can't get any way to proceed.Please explain what you want to say sir.

Comment: sir please explain

Comment: @DebprasadKundu What is your background? Do you know any group theory? For example, do you know what a kernel is? Do you know Lagrange's theorem? Do you know the first isomorphism theorem? You need to apply these concepts. By the isomorphism theorem, we have $GL_n(\Bbb Z_{p^m})/\ker\cong{\rm img}$. The range, or image, is all of ${\rm GL}_n(\Bbb Z_p)$, and you can count how many elements are in the kernel, and you know $|G/H|=|G|/|H|$ from Lagrange.

Comment: sir I'm getting confused in finding order of kernal sir. Please help me, I'm undergrad math student  and yes I know first isomorphism theorem and Lagrange's theorem as well. But I cant find order of the kernal and also cant understand why the  kernal is that type?

Comment: The kernel is all elements sent to the identity matrix. Thus, all the elements of the matrix must match that of the identity matrix mod $p$. Therefore, it must be the identity matrix plus a matrix with every element a multiple of $p$. The elements in $\Bbb Z_{p^m}$ which are a multiple of $p$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the elements of $\Bbb Z_{p^{m-1}}$.

Comment: sir what is the mapping so that the kernal is that type?

Comment: Do you know what the homomorphism $\Bbb Z_{p^m}\to\Bbb Z_p$ is? You take an integer mod $p^m$ and turn it into an integer mod $p$. You can do that to an entire matrix to get a ring homomorphism $M_n(\Bbb Z_{p^m})\to M_n(\Bbb Z_p)$, which in turn gives you a group homomorphism $GL_n(\Bbb Z_{p^m})\to GL_n(\Bbb Z_p)$.

Comment: sir sorry for the late reply. But how to determine kernel from it and how to evaluate carfinality of the kernal? Please help sir

Comment: I already said how to determine the kernel. What part of my explanation did you have trouble understanding? I don't feel comfortable "spoonfeeding" more than I already have here.